# Upgrading from Laravel 4.2 to Laravel 5 - Container

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I still have some trouble understanding all the changes from Laravel 4.2 to 5.0.

I have already managed to import all my models, controllers, config etc. I have namespaced almost everything but one thing that I can't seem to manage is to transform this code from 4.2 `app\filters.php` to my new 5.0 application.

Here's part of the code with some added explanations below that I'm having problems with. The following code was added so that we can conveniently ask for the permissions inside a group for all the actions/visible fields for the current user.

`if(App::make('Authflag', $usergroup->id)->can(GroupPermissions::EDIT_MEMBERS)) ...`

**Code from 4.2:**

```
App::before(function($request) {

    App::instance('Authflags', array()); 

    App::bind('Authflag', function($app, $param) {

        $authflags = App::make('Authflags'); 

        if(isset($authflags[$param]))
        {
            return $authflags[$param]; 
        }

        // Calculate generate flag value

        $authflags[$param] = $authflag; 

        App::instance('Authflags', $authflags);

        return $authflag;
    });

});
```

**Explanation:**

instance Authflags contains `group_id => permissionObject`

**Code explanation:**

- Get the Authflags array instance
- If we already have the needed permissionObject return it
- Else generate/calculate/request the permissionObject
- Update the Authflags instance
- Return the created permissionObject

But whatever I try I keep getting the `ReflectionException in Container.php line 776: Class Authflag does not exist.`

I tried to create a contract and a service and set a binding inside the `AppServiceProvider`. But I'm pretty sure I was doing a completely wrong/different thing.

I tried to just copy this code with some modifications inside the AppServiceProvder. But It just seemed wrong and didn't work.

(Come to think of it the whole code should have probably been inside the `start/global.php`)

**How can I port this code to Laravel 5.0?**

Comment: You have to use a middleware.

Comment: Middleware's are the "replacement" for the before/after Filtering

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Although I'm not sure, I think the `before/after` filter is irrelevant at the moment. Just today I started to think that I didn't need it at all and should have put the `App::bind` and `App::instance` directly in `global.php`. Or if you think I'm mistaken then could you please make an answer out the comment and show me how should I proceed? Eventually I want to be able to call `App::make('Authflag', $group_id)` again. But I have no idea where or how to make these bindings in Laravel 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a middleware "encapsulation". Here is an example, that will show where you would have to put your custom before and after parts of your app.

```
use Closure;

class ChangeCookieLifetime {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        //anything put here will be run BEFORE your app
        $response = $next($request);
        //anything put here will be run AFTER your app
        return $response
    }

}
```

In your particular case iw dould like this:

```
use Closure;

class ChangeCookieLifetime {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        App::instance('Authflags', array());

        App::bind('Authflag', function($app, $param) {

            $authflags = App::make('Authflags'); 
            if(isset($authflags[$param]))
            {
                return $authflags[$param]; 
            }

            // Calculate generate flag value
            $authflags[$param] = $authflag; 
            App::instance('Authflags', $authflags);
            return $authflag;
        });


        $response = $next($request);
        //anything put here will be run AFTER your app
        return $response
    }

}
```

Although I can't promise that the parts I inserted will work, this is the direct "translation" from Laravel 4.2 to Laravel 5

Comment: It worked! For anyone else stumbling on this question/answer I also found this helpful when trying to implement it: [L5 middleware filter style](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-middleware-filter-style)

Comment: I also read this article BUT that article doesn't make it as easy to understand as my example...

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean it like that. I totally agree. But after I read your answer I still had a bit of trouble to add this middleware to all the routes. And I got some extra information & knowledge from there. Just saying that it might also be useful to someone else.